# É possível obter o numero do SIM no firemonkey(Delphi)?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

É possível conseguir o número do celular (numero do SIM) no delphi firemonkey?
Estou procurando em forums a algumas horas e não achei nenhum exemplo o biblioteca que permita conseguir o numero do celular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for android:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Telephony;

var
  tMgr: JTelephonyManager;
  PhoneNumber: String;
begin
  tMgr := TJTelephonyManager.Wrap((SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) 
as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
  PhoneNumber := JStringToString(tMgr.getLine1Number);
end;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou